# getting list and list element name for a nested list in R

Tags: r, list

I made a nested list like the one below.

```
group1 <- list(color = c("red", "green", "blue"),taste = c("sweet", "sour"))
group2 <- list(color = c("orange","purple","yellow"),taste = c("tan", "salt"))
nestedlist <- list(group1, group2)
```

now from this "nested list", i want to find out the which group an element belongs and which list element it belongs. Pardon my lack of understanding with list structure.

For example

```
test <- c("red", "tan")
```

given test i want the return of "color" "group1" and "taste" "group2"..

Is there any function to do this? I struggle with lists often. any help would be appreciated

Comment: have you tried `nestedlist <- list(g1 = group1, g2 = group2)` instead of `nestedlist <- list(group1, group2)` ? This way, you can just do `unlist(nestedlist)` and search on that.

Comment: Fair point about the names, but it can become difficult when you have `nestedlist <- list(g2.g1 = group1, g2 = group2)` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to do it...

```
names(nestedlist) <- paste0("Group",1:length(nestedlist)) #add names to list
lookup <- unlist(nestedlist) #unlist, retaining names
names(lookup)[match(test,lookup)] #lookup matching names

[1] "Group1.color1" "Group2.taste1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
dat = lapply(test,function(z){sapply(nestedlist,function(x) 
                                        {sapply(x,function(y) {z %in% y})})})
do.call(rbind,lapply(dat, function(x) {c(group = which(sapply(x,any)),
                                 col = names(which(x[[which(sapply(x,any))]])))}))
```

Output:

```
     group col     
[1,] "1"   "color" 
[2,] "2"   "taste"
```

It also works if one group has more nested lists than the other, which was what I struggled with initially. Curious to see the solution of others, hope this helps!

Comment: I am getting below error: Error in x[[which(sapply(x, any))]] : 
  attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex